# Page tracking between two arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I've been catching up on jQuery and messing around, so I've been working on a slider for books in my spare time. I've been having the problem lately with the page tracking though. When you change between One page view and Two page view, it doesn't keep the page number that you were last one. Now right now I have it set up to two different variables because I benched that problem for awhile but now it's time to address it.

So before I tried to set them up to one variable, but it ended up skipping pages on the one page view. I did some screwing around but I'm honestly stumped on how to make this work.

tl;dr

When single page is on page 3, page 3 and 4 should show in the two page view.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ks4tj7r2/) [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/CoadyAu/pen/DziIf)**

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="slider_wrapper">
          <div id="multi_slider">
            <div id="result"></div>
            <span class="nvgt" id="prevtwo"></span>
            <span class="nvgt" id="nexttwo"></span>
          </div>
          <div id="single_slider">
            <div id="result1"></div>
            <span class="nvgt" id="prevone"></span>
            <span class="nvgt" id="nextone"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <a href="#" id="prevonebot">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" id="prevtwobot">Prev</a>
        <a href="#" id="1page">1 Page</a></span>
        <a href="#" id="2page">2 Pages</a></span>
        <a href="#" id="nexttwobot">Next</a>
        <a href="#" id="nextonebot">Next</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

var twopage = 
        ['<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%201"><img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%202">', 
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%203"><img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%204">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%205"><img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%206">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%207"><img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%208">']
var onepage = 
        ['<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%201">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%202">', 
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%203">', 
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%204">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%205">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%206">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%207">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%208">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%208">',
        '<img src="http://place-hold.it/256x512&text=page%208">']

counterOne = -1;
counterTwo = -1;

  function imgTransitionOne() {
        $('#result1').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#result1').html(onepage[counterOne]);
            $('#result1 > img').on('load', function() {
                $('#result1').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    };

    function next1(){
        counterOne = (counterOne + 1) % onepage.length;
        console.log(counterOne);
          imgTransitionOne();
    };

    next1();

    $('#nextone').click(next1);

    $('#prevone').click(function () {
    if(counterOne=='0'){
    counterOne= onepage.length;
    }
    counterOne = (counterOne - 1); 
    console.log(onepage[counterOne]); 
    imgTransitionOne();
    });

    //One Page Bottom

   function imgTransitionOne() {
        $('#result1').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#result1').html(onepage[counterOne]);
            $('#result1 > img').on('load', function() {
                $('#result1').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    };

    function next1(){
        counterOne = (counterOne + 1) % onepage.length;
        console.log(counterOne);
          imgTransitionOne();
    };

    $('#nextonebot').click(next1);

    $('#prevonebot').click(function () {
    if(counterOne=='0'){
    counterOne= onepage.length;
    }
    counterOne = (counterOne - 1); 
    console.log(onepage[counterOne]); 
    imgTransitionOne();
    });

//Two Pages
   function imgTransitionTwo() {
        $('#result').fadeOut(300, function() {
            $('#result').html(twopage[counterTwo]);
            $('#result > img').on('load', function() {
                $('#result').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    };

    function next2(){
        counterTwo = (counterTwo + 1) % twopage.length;
        console.log(counterTwo);
          imgTransitionTwo();
    };

    next2();

    $('#nexttwo').click(next2);

    $('#prevtwo').click(function () {
    if(counterTwo=='0'){
    counterTwo= twopage.length;
    }
    counterTwo = (counterTwo - 1); 
    console.log(twopage[counterTwo]); 
    imgTransitionTwo();
    });

    //Two Pages Bottom
   function imgTransitionTwo() {
        $('#result').fadeOut(300, function() {
            $('#result').html(twopage[counterTwo]);
            $('#result > img').on('load', function() {
                $('#result').fadeIn(500);
            });
        });
    };

    function next2(){
        counterTwo = (counterTwo + 1) % twopage.length;
        console.log(counterTwo);
          imgTransitionTwo();
    };



    $('#nexttwobot').click(next2);

    $('#prevtwobot').click(function () {
    if(counterTwo=='0'){
    counterTwo= twopage.length;
    }
    counterTwo = (counterTwo - 1); 
    console.log(twopage[counterTwo]); 
    imgTransitionTwo();
    });



  });
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $("#single_slider").hide();

        $("#s2fitone").hide();
        $("#s2heightone").hide();
        $("#nextonebot").hide();
        $("#prevonebot").hide();


            $("#1page").click(function() {
                $("#multi_slider").hide();
                $("#single_slider").show();
$("#result1").show();
                $("#result").hide();
                $("#s2fitone").show();
                $("#s2heightone").show();
                $("#s2fittwo").hide();
                $("#s2heighttwo").hide();
                $("#nexttwobot").hide();
                $("#prevtwobot").hide();                
                $("#nextonebot").show();
                $("#prevonebot").show();
            });
            $("#2page").click(function() {
                $("#multi_slider").show();
                $("#single_slider").hide();
$("#result").show();
                $("#result1").hide();
                $("#s2fitone").hide();
                $("#s2heightone").hide();
                $("#s2fittwo").show();
                $("#s2heighttwo").show();
                $("#nexttwobot").show();
                $("#prevtwobot").show();                
                $("#nextonebot").hide();
                $("#prevonebot").hide();

            });
    });
```